# Do you get notifications if someone edits a Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I was looking through a Google Sheets for schoolwork after school, and I was the only person on the sheet. I think I may have accidentally deleted something, and a few moments after, a whole group of people came on. I was wondering if you get notifications if someone makes changes to a Google Sheets and am concerned, as it is shared across all of the freshman Bio classes.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each signed-in user who has at least view access to a spreadsheet can subscribe to notifications through **Tools > Notification settings**. These notifications are not automatic but need to be turned on manually, by the user themself, for every spreadsheet separately.